# Making a php regex code synthax highlighter

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "`[code]
<p>A paragraph</p>
<script>var a = 'stackoverflow';</script>
<div id='my_div'>a block element</div>
[/code]";
```

`preg_replace("@(&lt;.*?&gt;)@is","<span style='color: green;'>$1</span>");`

The above preg_replace transforms any `<tag>` to green. I however wanted to perform this operation only if `<tag>` is enclosed between `[code]` and `[/code]`. Like string variable above.

Comment: This can be done manipulating the DOM via JavaScript or jQuery instead of regex'es

Comment: I have a working javascript model. 

Using getElementsByTagName('code');  a for loop and the 'replace' function. It work well.

Am trying to broaden my scope using php with regex.

Comment: understood. Perhaps you can find other applications of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the long run, the regexp method can become really tedious, or impossible to achieve, regarding to your skills. It can even cause issue in specific cases (Imagine there is a green span inside [code][/code] => error ).

A more cleaner approach would be to parse your html string(s) so you would be able to navigate through your element, as you would do in javascript/jQuery.

The are many HTML parsing library in PHP, i'm still using [SimpleDomParser](http://ttp://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but you can easily grab another one.

So in your case, it would require first to extract eachs strings between "[code]" and "[/code]", parse them, search for valid elements in them, create a green span for each found then moving it inside.
Or something of this kind, regarding to your orgininal datas.

This library is not really convenient to work with, but the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) is clear, concise, with a lot of sample.

Answer (score 0):

You ***could*** come up with:

```
(?:
    (?:\[code\]
    |
    \G(?!\A))\s*\K)
(<([^ ]+)[^>]*>[\s\S]+?</\2>)
```

And replace this with `<style class='someclass'>$1</style>`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yA3oH5/1).

---

#### Explanation

```
(?:                           # a non capturing group
    (?:\[code\]               # match [code]
    |                         # or
    \G(?!\A))\s*\K)           # start at the previous match
                              # followed by whitespaces
(<([^ ]+)[^>]*>[\s\S]+?</\2>) # capture html tags to group 1/2 respectively
```

The clue is to use `\G` which allows you to match at the end of the previous match, thus allowing to look for patterns in a construct like `[code]` / `[/code]`, the rest is decorative (somewhat ;-))

---

In `PHP`:

```
$regex = '~(?:
           (?:\[code\]
           |
           \G(?!\A))\s*\K)
           (<([^ ]+)[^>]*>[\s\S]+?</\2>)
          ~x';
$string = preg_replace($regex, "<style class='someclass'>$1</style>", $your_string_here);
```

#### Demo

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/wBUVhV).